# Why can't find Jetty Setting In IntelliJ's Configurations

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-jetty-plugin

[image]

[image]

Why can't i see the setting like, "Path" or "WebApp Folder" in "Run/Debug Configurations"?
I have the lib for jetty runner and restart the intelJ.
I also try the old version of jetty but still can't fix it.

Comment: Looks like you are using some custom Jetty plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Once i revert the intelliJ to old version.
Then, fixed.